# How to integrate scrapyjs function into a Scrapy project

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I made a web scraper using the Scrapy Framework to get concert ticket data from [this website](http://www.vividseats.com/concerts/awolnation-tickets.html). I have been able to successfully scrape data from elements inside of each ticket that is on the page, except for the price which can only be accessed by clicking the "tickets" button to go to the tickets page and scraping a ticket price from a ticket on the page.

After extensive Googling, I found that Scrapy.js (which is based in Splash) can be used within Scrapy to interact with JavaScript on the page (such as the button that needs to be clicked). I have seen some basic examples of how Splash is used to interact with JavaScript, but none of them have featured Splash's integration with Scrapy (not even in the docs).

I've been following the format of using item loaders to store the scraped elements in a parse method and then making a request which is supposed go to another link and parse the html from that page by calling a second parse method

```
(e.g. yield scrapy.Request(next_link, callback=self.parse_price)
```

but the code for this would change somewhat now that I will be using Scrapy js. To incorporate the Scrapyjs, I was thinking of using functions similar to this:

```
function main(splash)
  splash:go("http://example.com")
  splash:wait(0.5)
  local title = splash:evaljs("document.title")
return {title=title}
```

from [this site](http://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash/) but since javascript can't be written directly inside of a python program, how/where would I even incorporate that kind of function in the program in order to be able to navigate to the next page by clicking the button and parse the html? I'm obviously very new at web scraping so any help at all would be greatly appreciated. The code for the spider is below:

### concert_ticket_spider.py

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider , Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import Join, MapCompose
from concert_comparator.items import ComparatorItem

bandname = raw_input("Enter a bandname \n")
vs_url = "http://www.vividseats.com/concerts/" + bandname + "-tickets.html"

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [416]
    name = 'comparator'
    allowed_domains = ["www.vividseats.com"]
    start_urls = [vs_url]
    #rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/' + bandname + '-.*', )), callback='parse_price'))
    # item = ComparatorItem()
    tickets_list_xpath = './/*[@itemtype="http://schema.org/Event"]'
    item_fields = {
        'eventName' : './/*[@class="productionsEvent"]/text()',
        'eventLocation' : './/*[@class = "productionsVenue"]/span[@itemprop  = "name"]/text()',
        'ticketsLink' : './/a/@href',
        'eventDate' : './/*[@class = "productionsDate"]/text()',
        'eventCity' : './/*[@class = "productionsVenue"]/span[@itemprop  = "address"]/span[@itemprop  = "addressLocality"]/text()',
        'eventState' : './/*[@class = "productionsVenue"]/span[@itemprop  = "address"]/span[@itemprop  = "addressRegion"]/text()',
        'eventTime' : './/*[@class = "productionsTime"]/text()'
    }


    item_fields2 = {
            'ticketPrice' : '//*[@class="eventTickets lastChild"]/div/div/@data-origin-price]',


   }
    def parse_price(self, response):
            l.add_xpath('ticketPrice','.//*[@class =  "price"]/text()' )
            yield l.load_item()


        def parse(self, response):
            """

            """

        selector = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        # iterate over tickets
        for ticket in selector.select(self.tickets_list_xpath):

            loader = XPathItemLoader(ComparatorItem(), selector=ticket)
            # define loader
            loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
            loader.default_output_processor = Join()
            # iterate over fields and add xpaths to the loader
            for field, xpath in self.item_fields.iteritems():
                loader.add_xpath(field, xpath)
                yield Request(vs_url, self.parse_result, meta= {
                    'splash': {
                        'args':{
                            #set rendering arguments here
                            'html' :1

                            # 'url' is prefilled from request url
                        },
                        #optional parameters
                        function main(splash)
                            splash:autoload("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js")
                            splash:go(vs_url)
                            splash:runjs("$('#some-button').click()")
                            return splash:html()
                        end                    
                        }
                    })
                for field, xpath in self.item_fields2.iteritems():
                    loader.add_xpath(field, xpath)

            yield loader.load_item()
```

Answer (score 1):

The key point here is that *`scrapyjs` provides a `scrapyjs.SplashMiddleware` middleware* that you need to [configure](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyjs#configuration). Then, every request that would have a [`splash` meta key](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyjs#usage) would be processed by the middleware.

FYI, I've personally successfully used `Scrapy` with `scrapyjs` before.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem is that the link for the tickets page has to be retrieved by clicking the tickets button using javascript, which will then be passed into the scrapy.Request. But since that javascript would have to be executed before the Request for the second page is made would I have to do a request on the first (current) page after the elements are scraped? Would you mind making a addition to the code I provided as an example just so I can get an idea, because i'm still really unclear as to how to proceed.

Comment: I've also already done the installation and configuration of scrapy js and splash listed [here](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyjs#configuration)

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 okay, but which "tickets" link do you need to click? Please provide a page url and the button location.

Comment: [Here](http://www.vividseats.com/concerts/awolnation-tickets.html) is the link that I have been using during testing. Basically if you look at the html for the page, each ticket (tr) in the table has a button called "tickets". I need to go to the link that the button will request and then scrape the lowest ticket price from the next page. So essentially, each time I scrape all of the specified elements from each ticket, it needs to also go to the next page to scrape the lowest price, load everything into the item, come back to the previous page and repeat the process.

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 well, there is an `a` element with `itemprop="url"` containing a direct link to tickets. Isn't it what you need? Thanks.

Comment: I am able to scrape the links (which I would have to concatenate to the current page's link) but I'm not really sure what the code would look like in order to follow the link inside of the for loop, get the price come back to the previous page and then repeat the process

Comment: @alexce I just made edits to my original parse function, this one loads all of the needed ticket elements into the item and then I tried to use splash to follow the button to the next page (which I think is probably wrong) and then nested another for loop in order to get the price (just based on code I found online). Do you mind looking over the code and just making edits so that it could actually follow the link, scrape, and then return to the previous page? Many thanks!

Comment: @alexce Another problem was that I won't have the link to the next page until I scrape the current page and I was having a problem trying to simultaneously scrape and request the new link before the item is yielded, which is why I was trying to use splash to render the next page